# UIPageControl hides under UITabBar

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbar, uipagecontrol

I am utilising a `UIPageViewController` with a `UIPageControl` to indicate the existing number of pages.

However when I put the whole viewcontroller inside a `UITabBarViewController`, the tab bar hides the `UIPageControl`.

My assumption has been that `UIPageControl` is a subview of my viewcontroller, hence when I put the viewcontroller inside a tabbar, the whole page should shrink as needed to make place for the tabbar. I didn't expect the tabbar to hide the lower part of the screen.

I have here a [small sample project](https://github.com/houmie/UIPageViewController)  to demonstrate the issue.

I suspect I have to limit the visible frame, is this correct? An advice would be great.

**UPDATE:**

My assumption was right. I just came up with this and it works:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake([[self view] bounds].origin.x,
                             [[self view] bounds].origin.y,
                             [[self view] bounds].size.width,
                             [[self view] bounds].size.height-10);
                             [[self.pageController view] setBounds:rect];
```

If there is a better way to do this, happy to know. Otherwise I put this as an answer.

Answer (score 12):

I encountered the same problem using storyboards.

I fixed the problem by removing the check on the "Under Bottom Bars" of the view controller displaying my pageViewController.